# Completion for a QLineEdit with multiple models/categories

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qlineedit, qabstractitemmodel, qcompleter

I'd like to build a completion for a `QLineEdit` which can take several completion models and organizes them as categories.

I have a working solution based on a `QSortFilterProxyModel` and a tree model for the items:

[image: completion]

The root items in the model show up as category, and the children of each root-item show up as filtered items. Then there's a customized `QTreeView` so this is displayed properly, tabbing ignores categories, etc.

This works fine - however it makes it very hard to write new completions (e.g. for the possible values for a setting).

Each completion needs to be a tree model with all categories in it. I'd prefer to write simple list models for each category, and then being able to combine them to a `QTreeModel`, i.e. something like this (pseudo-ish Python code):

```
commands = CommandListModel()
settings = SettingListModel()

completion.setModels([('commands', commands), ('settings', settings)])
```

There are some different solutions I had in mind, but I'm not sure what route to go, as all of them feel non-trivial to implement:

- Write a `QAbstractProxyModel`-like class (or a custom model) which combines several list models to one tree model, and leave the view part as-is.

Writing custom tree models in Python is hard however (and typically segfaults if you do *anything* wrong), and I've had performance issues with it in the past (compared to a `QStandardItemModel`, as there are some thousand items in the underlying models).

- Write functions for each model which fill a tree model (given a category and a list of items).

This makes it harder to write dynamic models rather than just having a list of static items.

- Use several list models, and adjust the view to be a `QVBoxLayout` of `QListView`s.

This sounds the most promising to me so far. However, implementing tabbing through the completion and filtering so it works right might be troublesome as well, and resizing the sub-views appropriately too.

Is there some easier way to do this I haven't considered? Which approach is likely to be the least painful down the road?

Comment: Easier - no. I think it's good to create your own `QAbstractItemModel` (not proxy) that will "merge" any of models according to your logic. But this task is very complex.